# restoring old record tape record with dying batteries

Tags: battery, record

I have an old record, recorded on a tape recorder. At a certain point, the batteries begun to die, so the record begins to have a higher and higher pitch.
I tried fixing it with some some software a few years a go, but the problem is that the pitch changes, so i could not properly fix it for the whole bad area, and i put the project on hold at the time. However, the developer in me tells me that the pitch changes linearly so i should be able to fix the record if i had so programming language to work with.
Do you know any software that would allow me to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: This is off topic here. You may want to look at the software recommendations Stack Exchange site.